# NMaximize is not converging to a solution

Tags: functions, maximum

I am trying to use `NMaximize` to find the maximum value of a variable that satisfies the given constraints. Since the constraints aren't straightforward, I am using the function.

I can see the constraints are such that the value is bounded but I get the below warning messages:

> NMaximize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or
>   precision within 100000 iterations.
>
> NMaximize::cvdiv: Failed to
>   converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded.

The constraint and the way I am using the function is as below:

```
    constraint = (x | y) \[Element] 
  Integers && ((x == 0 && 1. <= y <= 12720.) || (1. <= x <= 10712. && 
     0 <= y < 
      2.08565*10^-36 (3.04959*10^39 + 2.24751*10^34 x) + 
       2.8484*10^-43 Sqrt[
        4.98614*10^92 + 4.65469*10^88 x - 
         3.63201*10^84 x^2]) || (10713. <= x <= 19762. && 
     2.08565*10^-36 (3.04959*10^39 + 2.24751*10^34 x) - 
       2.8484*10^-43 Sqrt[
        4.98614*10^92 + 4.65469*10^88 x - 3.63201*10^84 x^2] < y < 
      2.08565*10^-36 (3.04959*10^39 + 2.24751*10^34 x) + 
       2.8484*10^-43 Sqrt[
        4.98614*10^92 + 4.65469*10^88 x - 3.63201*10^84 x^2]))


maxX =  
 NMaximize[{x, constraint}, {x, y}, MaxIterations -> 100000]
```

I have increased the `MaxIterations` from 100 to 100000 but it doesn't seem to converge. I am not sure if increasing the `MaxIterations` is the solution. Can you please guide me with this?

Comment: Could try maximizing over individual regions of the piecewise set-up. But the machine precision values will make validation of inequalities kind of iffy.

Comment: I'm not seeing what $y$ has to do with this.  Wouldn't the maximum value of $x$ be 19762?  `constraint /. x -> 19762` results in `y \[Element] Integers && 7229.16 < y < 7344.29` and `constraint /. x -> 19763` results in `False`.

Comment: @JimB, I think for `x`, `y` isn't needed. Thanks for pointing this out. But if I am trying to maximize `y`, I need to maximize over both the variables since `y` is an expression of `x`, right?

Comment: Yes, if that's what you want.  The general solution appears to be $x = 19762$ and $7230\leq y \leq 7344$.  So to maximize $y$ you'd choose $7344$.

Comment: @JimB, thank you. But I think the value of $y$ can be greater than 7344 for different values of $x$. For example, at $x = 7504$, the maximum value of y is 13937.

Comment: OK.  I was assuming that you were conditioning on the maximum value of $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) the constraint:

```
constraint2 = ((x == 0 && 1. <= y <= 12720.) || (1. <= x <= 10712. && 
        0 <= y < 2.08565*10^-36 (3.04959*10^39 + 2.24751*10^34 x) + 
          2.8484*10^-1 Sqrt[
            4.98614*10^8 + 4.65469*10^4 x - 3.63201 x^2]) || (10713. <= x <= 
         19762. && 
        2.08565*10^-36 (3.04959*10^39 + 2.24751*10^34 x) - 
          2.8484*10^-1 Sqrt[4.98614*10^8 + 4.65469*10^4 x - 3.63201 x^2] < y <
          2.08565*10^-36 (3.04959*10^39 + 2.24751*10^34 x) + 
          2.8484*10^-1 Sqrt[4.98614*10^8 + 4.65469*10^4 x - 3.63201 x^2])) // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] & // Simplify;
```

With the `Rationalized` constraint you can use [`Maximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html):

```
maxX = Maximize[{x, constraint2}, {x, y}]

(* {19762, {x -> 19762, y -> 7287}} *)

constraint2 /. maxX[[2]]

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** To find maximum `y`

```
(maxY = Maximize[{y, constraint2}, {x, y}]) // N
```

[image]

To plot the region defined by the constraint:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[constraint2, {x, y}];

Region[reg,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
 Epilog -> {Red,
   AbsolutePointSize[3],
   Point[{x, y} /. maxX[[2]]],
   Point[{x, y} /. maxY[[2]]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have numbers spread a wide range of magnitudes for no good reason. This range is probably too wide for machine precision arithmetic. Also telling `NMinimize` explicitly that this an integer optimization problem seems to help. Try this:

```
constraint2 = ((x == 0 && 1. <= y <= 12720.) || (1. <= x <= 10712. && 
      0 <= y < 
       2.08565*10^-36 (3.04959*10^39 + 2.24751*10^34 x) + 
        2.8484*10^-1 Sqrt[
          4.98614*10^8 + 4.65469*10^4 x - 3.63201 x^2]) || (10713. <= 
       x <= 19762. && 
      2.08565*10^-36 (3.04959*10^39 + 2.24751*10^34 x) - 
        2.8484*10^-1 Sqrt[
          4.98614*10^8 + 4.65469*10^4 x - 3.63201 x^2] < y < 
       2.08565*10^-36 (3.04959*10^39 + 2.24751*10^34 x) + 
        2.8484*10^-1 Sqrt[
          4.98614*10^8 + 4.65469*10^4 x - 3.63201 x^2])) // Expand

maxX = NMaximize[{x, constraint2}, {x, y}, Integers, 
  MaxIterations -> 10000]
```

> {19762., {x -> 19762, y -> 7311}}

And with your definition of `constraint`:

```
constraint /. maxX[[2]]
```

> True

Comment: But `constraint /. x -> 19762 /. y -> 8647` results in `False`?

Comment: @JimB D'oh. Yeah, I did the simplification wrong. -.- Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, thank you for this. This works for `x` but when I try to find the maximum `y` similarly, I still get the same message - `NMaximize[{y, res}, {x, y}, Integers, MaxIterations -> 100000]`. Output: NMaximize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded.